# How to submit form with get method jQuery and be on another page

Tags: jquery, redirect, methods, get

i have problems with jQuery submit form using get method.

When i submit my form i got values at the end of index.php (for example /index.php?cat=138&subcat=54 , but i want that values on another page for example /results.php?cat=138&subcat=54

My code is

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
      (function($){
        $(function(){
          $('select').selectToAutocomplete();
          $('#rezultat').submit(function(event){
            $( "#rezultat" ).submit()
          });
        });
      })(jQuery);
    </script>
```

PHP code is

```
<form method="get" id="rezutat" action="rezultati.php">
            <select name="cat" id="polazak" autofocus="autofocus" autocorrect="off" autocomplete="off">
                <option value="Odaberite mjesto polaska" selected="selected">...echo "</select>"; 



    ?>

            <select name="subcat" id="odrediste" >
                <option value="Odaberite odredište" selected="selected"></option>
    <?php
                    </option>"."<br/>";
                    }
                    echo "</select>"; 
    ?>
        <input type="submit" value="Traži">
```

Thanx for helping

Comment: Why do you use jquery to submit the form? your don't need to listen to the submit event just to submit it, that's what happens naturally.

Comment: Also - I'm guessing you have more then one `form` tags?

Comment: *"When i submit my form i got values at the end of index.php"* You realize that's exactly what a GET request is supposed to do, right?

Comment: i realize that but i want that extension at the end of another page.

i have only one form but i use jQuery autocomplete script and that script collect both inputs. When i type 2 inputs i have to send them to another file and show results 

when i submit form i get index.php?something, and i want get results.php?something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do:

```
$('#rezultat').submit(function(event){
  cat = //read out category
  subcat = //read out subcategory
  window.open ('results.php?cat='+cat+'&subcat='+subcat ,'_self',false);
  return false;
});
```

Comment: Thx, this is solution

Answer (score 0):

You don't need jquery to submit the form, setting the method to GET will do what you want. You might want to consider setting the target attribute though or try setting the action to ./rezultati.php as below:

```
<form method="get" id="rezultat" action="./rezultati.php" target="_self">
  <select name="cat" id="country-selector" autofocus="autofocus" autocorrect="off" autocomplete="off">

  </select> 
<input type="submit" value="Traži">
</form>
```

It also helps to post the full code you're trying to use, or at least a correct subset. Your form was lacking a closing tag, you had the 'echo' thing in the select and the PHP closing tag so it's hard to tell if those are real errors or just from your posting.